# Custom jQuery Mobile Theme won't apply Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to apply my own Theme made with jQuery Mobile Themeroller to my Wordpress Theme. But somehow it won't apply.

Here is my header.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>
        <?php
            if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
                single_tag_title("Tag Archive for &quot;"); echo '&quot; - '; }
            elseif (is_archive()) {
                wp_title(''); echo ' Archive - '; }
            elseif (is_search()) {
                echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; - '; }
            elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
                wp_title(''); echo ' - '; }
            elseif (is_404()) {
                echo 'Not Found - '; }
            if (is_home()) {
                bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); }
            else {
                bloginfo('name'); }
            if ($paged>1) {
                echo ' - page '. $paged; }
        ?>
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icon-ipad.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/icon-iphone4.png" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/splash.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x920" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/splash-iphone4.png" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" /> 



<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/CustomTheme.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <?php
    wp_head();
?>
</head> 

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Also tried the the custom css before the jQM CSS and the code that is given with Theme.zip when you download it at themeroller

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/CustomTheme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

can you see any problems why it won't apply?

Comment: In that case I see a "broken" theme with no colors at all.

Comment: Colors or page structure/jQM look isn't being applied?

Comment: You should probably use the `get_template_directory_uri` function or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: @Omar this is how my wordpress looks with structure css first [Link](http://i59.tinypic.com/k15jlw.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you're add `data-theme` to elements?

Comment: Yes, I am. If I only use the JQM CSS it works great. In only get the problem when I try to add my custom theme.

Comment: Your theme path is wrong then, `themes/CustomTheme.min.css` means the current directory, so `yoursite.com/themes/CustomTheme.min.css - which probably doesn't exist.` If you check your debugger (ie `Firebug` or `Chrome developer tools`, then you will see the `404` error, and where it's trying to get the .css file from.

Comment: @NickR you are right, I get the 404 error. Currently I'm only working with XAMPP. How can I fix the path? As I said before I already use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />`

Comment: `bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>` - will echo the main stylesheet - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri. You need to use this function `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` -  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri and then add the filename at the end.

Comment: @NickR add an answer.

Comment: Don't have time to expand on the answer at the moment - If someone else wants to, go for it :)